# Segmentation fault on RHEL environment 7.4 (works on RHEL 6)

Tags: python, segmentation-fault, libxml2, rhel, rhel7

I have a in-house python program that ships with python interpreter and some libraries to production. It works fine on RHEL 6 environments.

However on RHEL 7.4 it some how throws segmentation fault.
We suspect system library is being overriden by application library libxml2.

Backtrace :

```
(gdb) backtrace
#0  0x00007ffff7228e00 in __strncmp_sse42 () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007ffff03b3a48 in __xmlParserInputBufferCreateFilename (URI=0x9c7f3c "/opt/monitor/tools/etc/pmonspec.xml", enc=XML_CHAR_ENCODING_NONE) at xmlIO.c:2476
#2  0x00007ffff038cd44 in xmlNewInputFromFile__internal_alias (ctxt=0xa012a0, filename=0x9c7f3c "/opt/monitor/tools/etc/pmonspec.xml") at parserInternals.c:1463
#3  0x00007ffff03b59a2 in xmlDefaultExternalEntityLoader (URL=0x9c7f3c "/opt/monitor/tools/etc/pmonspec.xml", ID=0x0, ctxt=0xa012a0) at xmlIO.c:3832
#4  0x00007ffff085d722 in __pyx_f_4lxml_5etree__local_resolver (__pyx_v_c_url=0x9c7f3c "/opt/monitor/tools/etc/pmonspec.xml", __pyx_v_c_pubid=0x0, __pyx_v_c_context=0xa012a0)
    at src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:63618
#5  0x00007ffff03a4bd0 in xmlCtxtReadFile__internal_alias (ctxt=0xa012a0, filename=0x9c7f3c "/opt/monitor/tools/etc/pmonspec.xml", encoding=0x0, options=83970) at parser.c:14487
#6  0x00007ffff08754b4 in __pyx_f_4lxml_5etree_11_BaseParser__parseDocFromFile (__pyx_v_self=0x7b6640, __pyx_v_c_filename=0x9c7f3c "/opt/monitor/tools/etc/pmonspec.xml")
    at src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:68146
#7  0x00007ffff083316f in __pyx_f_4lxml_5etree__parseDocFromFile (__pyx_v_filename8=0x9c7f18, __pyx_v_parser=0x7b6640) at src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:71175
#8  0x00007ffff0833239 in __pyx_f_4lxml_5etree__parseDocumentFromURL (__pyx_v_url=0x7fffffffda14, __pyx_v_parser=0x7fff00000000) at src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:72080
#9  0x00007ffff0885768 in __pyx_f_4lxml_5etree__parseDocument (__pyx_v_source=0x9c7f18, __pyx_v_parser=0x66d2b0 <_Py_NoneStruct>, __pyx_v_base_url=0x66d2b0 <_Py_NoneStruct>)
    at src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:71797
#10 0x00007ffff08863aa in __pyx_pf_4lxml_5etree_12_ElementTree_parse (__pyx_v_self=0x9cc170, __pyx_args=<optimized out>, __pyx_kwds=<optimized out>) at src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:39625
#11 0x00000000004a0476 in call_function (pp_stack=<optimized out>, oparg=<optimized out>) at Python/ceval.c:4012
#12 PyEval_EvalFrameEx (f=0x7f7170, throwflag=<optimized out>) at Python/ceval.c:2665
#13 0x00000000004a1f74 in PyEval_EvalCodeEx (co=0x7ffff7ee63b0, globals=<optimized out>, locals=<optimized out>, args=0x0, argcount=0, kws=0x0, kwcount=0, defs=0x0, defcount=0, closure=0x0)
    at Python/ceval.c:3252
#14 0x00000000004a20f2 in PyEval_EvalCode (co=0x7fffffffda14, globals=0x7fff00000000, locals=0x4) at Python/ceval.c:666
#15 0x00000000004c4e90 in run_mod (mod=<optimized out>, filename=<optimized out>, globals=0x7fff00000000, locals=0x4, flags=<optimized out>, arena=<optimized out>) at Python/pythonrun.c:1346
#16 PyRun_FileExFlags (fp=0x776630, filename=0x7fffffffe615 "/opt/monitor/tools/bin/pmon_my", start=<optimized out>, globals=0x6f2140, locals=0x6f2140, closeit=1, flags=0x7fffffffe1ac)
    at Python/pythonrun.c:1332
#17 0x00000000004c6109 in PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags (fp=0x776630, filename=0x7fffffffe615 "/opt/monitor/tools/bin/pmon_my", closeit=1, flags=0x7fffffffe1ac) at Python/pythonrun.c:936
#18 0x000000000041462c in Py_Main (argc=<optimized out>, argv=0x7fffffffe358) at Modules/main.c:599
#19 0x00007ffff7114c05 in __libc_start_main () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#20 0x0000000000413aba in _start ()
```

I am assuming 2 solutions to this
1. Add latest libraries (libxml2) for rhel 7.4 in application lib folder. But then how to make python understand to use it ?
2. Reroute library search, linking and loading to look into application lib folder instead of using system.

Is it related to following change ?

Bug 1292230 - ld doesn't resolve symbols in linked to library

Surprisingly running the program in valgrind with trace-children option does not give any error.

Comment: I'm pretty certain you can't [easily] take a python binary from a RHEL 6 box and just run it on RHEL 7. The binary was built and linked against SOs that just aren't going to be on RHEL 7. Some things might work if ABI compatibility hasn't been broken, but I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: Recompile the source code and the dependencies on the RHEL 7.x system and it should be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I redirected symlink in application folder to point to system library at /usr/lib64/libxml2.so.2. With this it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, your application uses a private and outdated version of libxml2 that is affected by a [bug fixed in 2010](https://git.gnome.org//browse/libxml2/commit/?id=a7e79f28689c574e0bbef17f4cb3da00249181ff). Whether the issue is triggered also seems to depend on the particular version of zlib. You should upgrade to libxml2 2.7.7 or newer. If you linked against libxml2 statically, there's no other way than to recompile your application. I'd suggest to link dynamically against your system libxml2.

Comment: I redirected symlink in application folder to point to system library at /usr/lib64/libxml2.so.2.
With this it is working fine.